# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while running jar

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I use SLF4J logger. `jar` file is placed in `../lib` directory. Application was created using maven and in Netbeans. But I want to do all by myself to teach myself.

Application is compiled with command (of course there are no spaces after semicolons - I added them for better readability):

```
javac -cp ../lib/poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar;
  ../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar;
  ../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar;
  ../lib/commons-io-1.4.jar 
-d target/classes src\main\java\pl\alden\convertcosts\*.java
```

and I can run it with

```
java -cp ../lib/poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar;
  ../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar;
  ../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar;
  ../lib/commons-io-1.4.jar;
  ../lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar;
  target/classes
  pl/alden/convertcosts/App
```

I know I can set all jar files as cl`classpath` system variable (Windows 7).

I want to put all into `jar` and run it from this `jar`. To create `jar` I use

```
jar cvfm convertcosts.jar manifest.mf -C target/classes/ .
```

And I have proper `jar`: `jar tf convertcosts.jar` gives

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
.netbeans_automatic_build
log4j.properties
pl/
pl/alden/
pl/alden/convertcosts/
pl/alden/convertcosts/App.class
pl/alden/convertcosts/ConvertCostsException.class
...
```

Now I want to run application from `bat` file:

```
set classpath=../lib/poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar;
  ../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar;
  ../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar;
  ../lib/commons-io-1.4.jar;
  ../lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
java -jar convertcosts.jar
```

As a result I have

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
  at pl.alden.convertcosts.App.<clinit>(App.java:10)
```

To me it looks like main `jar` file does not see library `jar` files.

What should I change?

Comment: I would type in the full path to the library.

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html the environment variable is all upper case `CLASSPATH`. Try changing that. I'm not sure if it matters. Also if the original CLASSPATH is not empty, add to it rather than replacing it entirely -- the problem could be that it's failing to load SLF4J because some class that *it* needs is not on the path.

Comment: @Mukus Typing relational path works well when using `java` and `javac` - is there any difference whrn using `java -jar`?
@Jerry101 I changed classpath to CLASSPATH and result is same.

Answer (score 0):

Better to stick with the explicit command-line classpath definition:

```
java -cp ../lib/poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar;
  ../lib/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar;
  ../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar;
  ../lib/commons-io-1.4.jar;
  ../lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
  -jar convertcosts.jar
```

Defining `classpath` or `CLASSPATH` environment variable has a system-wide affect and you should be aware that not all java applications need these particular jars on their classpath. If you really must, then at the very least use the full paths instead of `../lib/` when defining the value of the `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: I tried this solution first (not mentioned - my fault).