# Why I'm Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while using jar which use poi jars

Tags: java, jar

I'm using Eclipse in order to compile & run Java applications. I'm creating several projects, which I export as a jar file and import (add to build path) them as jar file in the other projects. I add the jar as follows:

- copy the jar to the project I want
- right click on the jar -> build path -> add to build path

It is my first time I'm getting this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

I created a project which uses POI jars. The project name is "A". I export this project to A.jar file and import it (add to build path) in B project.
When I'm running the B project and try to init (call the constructor) of an object from A.jar, I'm getting the following error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle

I checked the following threads:

- [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)
- [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while running jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519378/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-while-running-jar)

But didn't find the answer.

1. Why am I getting this error? It isn't my first time, that I'm importing/adding to build path. But now I'm getting an error.
2. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You get the error, because the classloader do not find the class.
2. You have to add the jar that containing the class `poi-<version>.jar` to the classpath.

The build path only defined the path for the compiler. It not define that the class is in the classpath at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. So if I have project A.jar and project B.jar use A.jar. So project C jar which use B.jar must contain A.jar and B.jar ? Why it is not enough to contain only the B.jar (seem the right logic way... no ?)

Comment: @user3668129  Because A.jar does not contains B.jar. If you use a deependency management like maven it will be manage such dependency.